# Getting files to be included in dist folder

Tags: angular

I have created a new Angular 6 project. Then I have another framework I want to use called core UI. I add all the files within the src folder in a folder called coreui. I then change my index.html file in the src folder to reflect the new UI. Everything works as expected. But when i run ng build, the new coreui files are not copied to the dist library. How do I tell Angular to do that?

Comment: Add the `coreui` directory into the `assets` array of `angular.json`. They will end up in a subdirectory of `dist` called `coreui`

Comment: Thanks. It almost works. I tried:    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "*.*",
                "input": "/coreui/",
                "output": "coreui"
              }
            ],  But this only copy files and not folder, sub folders and files. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I started with just writinf the folder name but then i get an error saying. The /coreui asset path must start with the project source root. If I do the settings above i copies files from the folder, but not recursive.

Comment: You should be able to just use `src/coreui` as a string

Comment: That worked, thanks. Now that introduces another problem:D So I moved the coreui folder to the src folder. In the index.html i have to reference like this  <link href="/src/coreui/vendors/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. However in the dist folder there is no src folder. So my references changes when doing a build.

Comment: If the core UI directory is the one in your assets array, then shouldn't need to include src in the href

Comment: Your right, thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything included in the assets will be copied over to the dist directory, so in `angular.json`, add the following to the `assets` array:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    //.. All your other values
    "src/coreui" // Add this line
]
```

This will copy over the `coreui` directory into `dist`